# Dimension of intersections of affine algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if I could verify this with someone. I could only find it for when everything is projective but I am guessing it is true for affine as well. Let $X,Y\subset \mathbb A^n_k$ be algebraic sets.  Does it then follows that
$$ \operatorname {codim}  (X\cap Y) \leq \operatorname {codim} X+\operatorname {codim}Y.$$

Comment: Take $X$ to be $x=0$, where $x$ is a co-ordinate function and $Y$ to be $x=1$. Then both codimensions are one, but the codimension of $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ is not less than or equal to 2.

Comment: Does it hold as long as the intersection is non-empty?

Comment: It does and follows from Krull's principal ideal theorem and the lovely diagonal trick of Serre.

Comment: Would you happen to know where I could reference this fact by any chance?

Comment: A proof can be found in Serre's Local Algebra.